# Android Studio spurious "Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function"

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface

Android Studio is showing this error. Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    static native void runTests(String path);

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("TestLib");
    }
}
```

In that first line, **runTests** is highlit in red and if you hover over it, you see the message "Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function"

To be clear, the app *does* build and run just fine. It's just that Android Studio thinks that this symbol can't be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. If my function is defined using the standard naming convention, e.g.

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_myapplication_MainActivity_runTests(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jstring path)
```

Then Android Studio figures it out.

My problem was that I was just defining it as

```
static void
runTests(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jstring path)
```

and using `env->RegisterNatives()` to link it into Java. It was too much to ask of Android Studio to figure that out.